# how select content value cell when update row jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I can edit jqgrid row as follows. When I edit inline, when click on cell when edit row .select content value cell or highlight cells content value
 this demo plaese see demo: https://jsfiddle.net/amir3164/dnfk8hmr/156/
  i want this like imge 
[image]

this my code when edit

```
  $grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        colModel: [
            { name: "act", template: "actions" },
            { name: "id", width: 50, template: "integer" },
            { name: "get", width: 50, template: "integer" },
            { name: "PackageCode", width: 110 , editable: true },
            { name: "Name", width: 200, editable: true }
        ],
 inlineNavOptions: {
            add: true,
            edit: true,
            addParams: {
                position: "last", //ردیف‌های جدید در آخر ظاهر می
                rowID: function (options) {
                    return 123 + $.jgrid.guid++;
                },
                useDefValues: true
            }
        }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar")
        .jqGrid("navGrid")
      .jqGrid("inlineNav");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use [HTMLInputElement.select()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method on the `<input>` element after inline editing will be started. The corresponding code could be the following:

```js
inlineEditing: {
    focusField: "PackageCode",
    oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
        var $control = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid + "_PackageCode"));
        if ($control.length > 0) {
            $control[0].select();
        }
    }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/159/

**UPDATED**: The select the input text onClick one need to call `select()` inside of onClick or onFocus event handler. For example, to make onClick binding for all editing fields you can use `cmTemplate`:

```js
cmTemplate: {
    editoptions: {
        dataEvents: [ 
            {
                type: "click",
                fn: function () {
                        $(this).select();
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/161/

Comment: thanks .but  i want  when click on textbox select content value .for sample when click name .select content value when inline edit

Comment: @saeed3164: See Updated part of my answer.